# How to figure out which key of ModelState has error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

How do I figure out which of the keys in ModelState that contains an error when ModelState.IsValid is false? Usually I would just hover the mouse thru the ModelState.Values list checking item by item for error count > 0. But now I'm working on a view that has some lists of complex objects, totalling 252 ModelState items(each item of each object of each list has an entry on ModelState.Keys).

So, is there an easier way to point out the error source?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can check the `ViewData.ModelState.Values` collection and see what are the Errors.

```
[Httpost]
public ActionResult Create(User model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     //Save and redirect
   }
   else
   {
     foreach (var modelStateVal in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
     {
       foreach (var error in modelStateVal.Errors)
       {               
          var errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
          var exception = error.Exception;
          // You may log the errors if you want
       }
     }
   }         
   return View(model);
 }
}
```

If you really want the Keys(the property name), You can iterate through the `ModelState.Keys`

```
foreach (var modelStateKey in ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
{
    var modelStateVal = ViewData.ModelState[modelStateKey];
    foreach (var error in modelStateVal.Errors)
    {
        var key = modelStateKey; 
        var errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
        var exception = error.Exception;
        // You may log the errors if you want
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me find the problem. Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but solved anyways...

thanks!

Comment: This works, but doesn't answer the question; how to find out which KEY of the ModelState has an error. In this solution, we get the error, but not the key this error belongs to. How do we achieve that?

Comment: @RensdeNobel I updated the answer to include that as well.

Comment: The `Key` seems to include some GUID. Don't forget to sanitize it.

Comment: It is baffling to me why the validation error collection is implemented this way where you cannot simply select the errors based on key (or part of the key) e.g. ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where(w => w.Key.StartsWith("something")).

I guess they have their reasons.

Answer (score 3):

```
ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

is considered cleaner.

Comment: This returns only error messages without keys. Not really what OP is looking for.

Comment: ModelState.Keys

Answer (score 1):

where modelState is a ModelStateDictionary object

```
foreach (var keyModelStatePair in modelState)
    {
        var key = keyModelStatePair.Key;
        var errors = keyModelStatePair.Value.Errors;
        if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
        {
            var errorMessages = errors.Select(error =>
            {
                return error.ErrorMessage;
            }).ToArray();

            // do something with your keys and errorMessages here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a long time and finally I found it. In my case, it was the Id field :)

Just place a breakpoint and check your ModelState in runtime and go to this section :

ModelState -> Root -> Children

and you will see all valid and invalid Keys

[image]

Comment: I don't have a "Root" element in my case.

Answer (score 1):

following method Gives Dictionary Response of errors can Return it In `Badrequest` Based on th functionality.

```
        var ErrorDictionary=ModelState
                .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .ToList()
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList());
```

Comment: You can remove the `.List()` part.

Answer (score 0):

Did some modification to the solution provided by @cblanto7.

```
    _logger.LogInformation("ModelState is not valid: In yourmodelName/yourActionName.");
    foreach (var keyModelStatePair in ModelState)
    {
        var errors = keyModelStatePair.Value.Errors;
        if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
        {
            var key = keyModelStatePair.Key;
            var errorMessageArray = errors.Select(error =>
            {
                return error.ErrorMessage;
            }).ToArray();

            var errorMessages = string.Join(", ", errorMessageArray); 
            _logger.LogInformation($"ModelState is not valid:{key} has {errorMessages}");
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Upender Reddy's answer, I just got this very practical expression to use on the Watch window for debugging:

```
ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
```

Just notice that `ModelState` is from type `ModelStateDictionary`, which  implements `IDictionary<string, ModelState>` interface, so it means one can use LINQ methods on it.